# MySQL Complex Count Issue

Tags: mysql, count

I am trying to do a query whereby if a football team wins a home game (e.g. Liverpool FC) then a 1 is added to a column, and the same for a loss (which would be AwayWins, and a draw would be 'Draw').

The following query works great, it just compares the goals scores and adds the 1 in the appropriate place.

```
SELECT *,
    IF(max(`goalsHomeTeam`)>`awayTeamName`,'1','') as HomeWins,
    IF(max(`goalsHomeTeam`)<`awayTeamName`,'1','') as AwayWins,
    IF(max(`goalsHomeTeam`)=`awayTeamName`,'1','') as Draw
FROM fixtures 
WHERE `homeTeamName` = 'Liverpool FC'
GROUP BY fixtures_id
LIMIT 10
```

And this looks like:

[image]

However, what I'd really like to display is just the 3 fields:

HomeWins, AwayWins and Draw

and then a count for each box (e.g. based on the picture above HomeWins: 9, AwayWins: 0 and Draw: 0.

I've tried adding simple stuff like wrapping a count around the IF's but that didn't work. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this query

```
SELECT 
    SUM(IF(`goalsHomeTeam` > `awayTeamName`,1,0)) AS HomeWins,
    SUM(IF(`goalsHomeTeam` < `awayTeamName`,1,0)) AS AwayWins,
    SUM(IF(`goalsHomeTeam` = `awayTeamName`,1,0)) AS Draw
FROM fixtures 
WHERE `homeTeamName` = 'Liverpool FC'
GROUP BY `homeTeamName`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
Select SUM(T1.HomeWins), SUM(T1.AwayWins), SUM(T1.Draw)
From (#your query here#) AS T1
```

and simple example that it works: http://rextester.com/SYQI26450

Comment: That would add them up not count, but also because they aren't real columns I get the following error "Unknown column"

Comment: You need to sum it now actually and try to add alias to suquery